# c++ variable keeps resetting instead of incrementing?

Tags: c++, arrays, counter

```
void RetailerOrder::addItem(Product* p)
{
    bool space = false;
    int counter = 0;
    while ((space == false) && (counter < manifest.size()))
    {
        if (manifest[counter] == nullptr);
        {
            manifest[counter] = p;
            space = true;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    if (space == false)
    {
        cout << "no space" << endl;
    }
}
```

Why does the counter reset to zero with each pass through the while loop? If I use it as it is, only the last product that I enter gets stored in the array because `i` is always 1. Is there a way to let the counter increase.

Comment: Semicolon at the end of `if(manifest[counter == nullptr);` may have something to do with it.

Comment: thank you! that was so simple I feel stupid lol

Comment: That's why instead of `space = true;` you should have used `goto fail;` :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (manifest[counter] == nullptr);  // << see here
{
    manifest[counter] = p;
    space = true;
}
```

That semi-colon at the end of your `if` statement means "if condition, do nothing".

Then the braced scope following that executes *always.*

It should instead be:

```
if (manifest[counter] == nullptr)
{
    manifest[counter] = p;
    space = true;
}
```

---

As an aside, I'm not a big fan of things like:

```
if (space == false) ...
```

since, if you name you boolean values intelligently, you can avoid the comparisons:

```
if (! foundSpace) ...
```

The intelligent naming means that the boolean variable itself should be readable, such as with `foundSpace` or `haveFinished` or `userIsClinicallyInsane`. Once it is, you don't need to compare it to boolean constants at all.

That greatly reduces the code size and avoids the reductio-ad-absurdum situation where you don't know when to *stop* comparing booleans to constants:

```
if ((((haveFinished == true) == true) != false) == true) ...
```

---

As a *second* aside, I value my vertical space greatly when looking at code and there are ways to simplify your code which make it shorter and, in my *opinion,* easier to understand.

Since you're only using `space` as a way to insert the item and exit the loop prematurely, you could use something like:

```
void RetailerOrder::addItem (Product* p) {
    // Check every possible slot.

    for (int i = 0; i < manifest.size(); i++) {
        // If one free, use it and exit.

        if (manifest[i] == nullptr) {
            manifest[i] = p;
            return;
        }
    }

    // None were free, complain bitterly.

    cout << "no space" << endl;
}
```

Still, that's a stylistic approach of mine and you should feel free to ignore it if you disagree.

The "multiple return points are bad" crowd may not like it but that's usually because they don't understand the reason *why* it's considered suspect, the inability to easily see the many code paths. With a function of this size, it's not really a issue.

Comment: I like this, thank you. I'm new to c++ so I haven't developed a clean-cut style yet but I will certainly try because it's much easier to read.